# How to detect what's slowing down my webapp?

Tags: angular, typescript

so my code works but something seems to slow down displaying my table, checked the speed in network on Chrome and data loads fine (1.81 secs), also when trying to use the filters or clicking on another link in the navbar, the reaction is pretty slow.
Here's the link to my code https://github.com/ace182/resume/tree/master/app%20viernes/src/app/tabla

```
TS

//Table
ngOnInit() {

    this.consulta();
    this.dtOptions = {
      pageLength: 15,
      responsive: true,
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      buttons: [
        'print',
        'excel'
      ],
      language: {
        search: 'Búsqueda',
        lengthMenu: 'Cantidad _MENU_ registros por pagina',
        emptyTable: 'No hay datos disponibles',
        info: 'Registro _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ consultados',
        infoEmpty: 'Registro 0 a 0 de 0 consultados',
        paginate: {
          first: 'Primero',
          last: 'Ultimo',
          next: 'Siguiente',
          previous: 'Anterior'
        }
      }
    };


  }

  ngOnDestroy():void{
    this.alive = false;
    // Do not forget to unsubscribe the event
    $.fn['dataTable'].ext.search.pop();
    this.dtTrigger.unsubscribe();
    return this.ngOnInit();

  }

//Getting data to fill my table
consulta() {
    this.service.getAll().pipe(takeWhile(() => this.alive)).subscribe(persons => {
      this.persons = persons;
      // Calling the DT trigger to manually render the table
      console.log(this.persons);
      this.dtTrigger.next();

    });
  }
```

Comment: Did you check the "performance" tab in Chrome - https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/

Comment: I just did, it says page loads in 4 secs... but actually takes 26 secs to completely load and functional... is there anything else in particular I should look at in performance? thanks for your reply btw